# Joomla 2.5 overriding /com_content/helpers/icons.php

Tags: joomla, overriding, joomla2.5

how to override this file in my own template file in Joomla 2.5 ?
/com_content/helpers/icon.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file isn't a view - so you can't override it - via the template.

This doc will provide clues:
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Can use this [plugin to override](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/15611?qh=YTo3OntpOjA7czo4OiJvdmVycmlkZSI7aToxO3M6MTE6Im92ZXJyaWRhYmxlIjtpOjI7czoxMDoib3ZlcnJpZGluZyI7aTozO3M6OToib3ZlcnJpZGVzIjtpOjQ7czoxMjoib3ZlcnJpZGVhYmxlIjtpOjU7czoxMDoiJ292ZXJyaWRlJyI7aTo2O3M6OToib3ZlcnJpZGVyIjt9)